# How do I get fgetcsv() in PHP to work with Japanese characters?

Tags: php, html, unicode, fopen

I have the following data being generated from a google spreadsheet rss feed.

```
いきます,go,5 
きます,come,5 
かえります,"go home, return",5 
がっこう,school,5 
スーパー,supermarket,5 
えき,station,5 
ひこうき,airplane,5
```

Using PHP I can do the following:

```
$url = 'http://google.com.....etc/etc';
$data = file_get_contents($url);

echo $data; // This prints all Japanese symbols
```

But if I use:

```
$url = 'http://google.com.....etc/etc';
$handle = fopen($url);

while($row = fgetcsv($handle)) {
    print_r($row); // Outputs [0]=>,[1]=>'go',[2]=>'5', etc, i.e. the Japanese characters are skipped
}
```

So it appears the Japanese characters are skipped when using either `fopen` or `fgetcsv`.

My file is saved as UTF-8, it has the PHP header to set it as UTF-8, and there is a meta tag in the HTML head to mark it as UTF-8. I don't think it's the document it's self because it can display characters through the `file_get_contents` method.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I can't add comment to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257990/how-do-i-get-fgetcsv-in-php-to-work-with-japanese-characters/6258130#6258130) from Darien*

I reproduce the problem, after change a locale the problem was solved.
You must install jp locale on server before trying repeat this.

**Ubuntu**
Add a new row to the file /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local

```
ja_JP.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

And run command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Or

```
sudo locale-gen
```

**Debian**
 Just execute "dpkg-reconfigure locales" and select necesary locales (ja_JP.UTF-8)

I don't know how do it for other systems, try searching by the keywords "locale-gen locale" for your server OS.

In the php file, before open csv file, add this line

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP.UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it might be the same as [PHP Bug 48507](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48507).

Have you tried changing your PHP [locale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) setting prior to running the code and resetting it afterwards?

Comment: Hmmm, does look like it matches the bug. I will try the locale setting and see if that makes a difference

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my Linux machine. (Copy-pasting the hiragana into a CSV file.) By default I believe it is operating as `en_US.utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider [this](http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/) library. I remember using it some time back, and it is much nicer than the built-in PHP functions for handling CSV files. がんばって！

Answer (score 0):

May be iconv character encoding help you

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by hand not using `fgetcsv` and friends:

```
<?php
$file = file('http://google.com.....etc/etc');
foreach ($file as $row) {
    $row = preg_split('/,(?!(?:[^",]|[^"],[^"])+")/', trim($row));
    foreach ($row as $n => $cell) {
        $cell = str_replace('\\"', '"', trim($cell, '"'));
        echo "$n > $cell\n";
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can opt in for a more fancy closures-savvy way:

```
<?php
$file = file('http://google.com.....etc/etc');

array_walk($file, function (&$row) {
    $row = preg_split('/,(?!(?:[^",]|[^"],[^"])+")/', trim($row));
    array_walk($row, function (&$cell) {
        $cell = str_replace('\\"', '"', trim($cell, '"'));
    });
});

foreach ($file as $row) foreach ($row as $n => $cell) {
    echo "$n > $cell\n";
}
```